# Run playbook periodically

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

we want to do backup using ansible and we want it to run periodically. I think its possible using os crontab to running playbook, but we want to have more neatly solution Is there any feature in ansible to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags on your question suggest a solution: Tower (or AWX) have scheduled jobs. Just Ansible Engine doesn't have a scheduler, so either that or your choice of third-party scheduler.

Running a backup does not really change the configuration state of a system. An alternate pattern is to write and maintain a backup script in your playbook. Deploy that with Ansible to the node that runs backups.